# I keep getting " 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Probably some easy fix, but I can't find it bruh. The code is with 2 procedures and the main menu image is an image and this is just a practice right now. I have provided the image and Credits.txt with the image. [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lN0X1P29KFi6iyKCVspbFjkWv8CPspjL/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnQY5.png)

```
#Importing all necessary scripts
import pygame
import time
import sys


#Initiating pygame
pygame.init()

#Creating the fonts for the game
Menufont = pygame.font.SysFont('Bahnschrift SemiBold', 70)

#Creating the window for where the game is able to be played
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

#Getting the height and the width of the screen into a variable
width = screen.get_width()
height = screen.get_height()

#Creating a Procedure for the Main Menu
def MainMenu():
    # Creating the main menu with a background image which has been modified to provide
    background = pygame.image.load('Main Menu Background.png')
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    # Creating text for the buttons for the main menu of the game
    PlaySolo = Menufont.render("Play Solo", True, (3, 3, 116))
    PlayMulti = Menufont.render("Play Multi", True, (3, 3, 116))
    Leaders = Menufont.render("Leaders", True, (3, 3, 116))
    Credits = Menufont.render("Credits", True, (3, 3, 116))
    Options = Menufont.render("Options", True, (3, 3, 116))
    Exit = Menufont.render("Exit", True, (3, 3, 116))

    # Placing the text for the buttons onto the main menu for the game
    screen.blit(PlaySolo, (229, 221))
    screen.blit(PlayMulti, (833, 221))
    screen.blit(Leaders, (243, 359))
    screen.blit(Credits, (863, 359))
    screen.blit(Options, (241, 492))
    screen.blit(Exit, (906, 492))

    # updating the menu for the game
    pygame.display.update()

    # This makes it so the cross in the corner is able to work
    Running = True
    while Running == True:
        # Provides information whilst the programme is running
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                # This gets the x and y co-ordinates for where the mouse is
                mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(mouse)
                # If the user presses the Play Solo Button
                if mouse[0] > 221 and mouse[0] < 454 and mouse[1] > 199 and mouse[1] < 289:
                    print("Play Solo")
                # If the user presses the Play Multi Button
                elif mouse[0] > 832 and mouse[0] < 1067 and mouse[1] > 199 and mouse[1] < 289:
                    print("Play Multi")
                # If the user presses the Leaders Button
                elif mouse[0] > 221 and mouse[0] < 454 and mouse[1] > 338 and mouse[1] < 428:
                    print("Leaders")
                # If the user presses the Credits Button
                elif mouse[0] > 832 and mouse[0] < 1067 and mouse[1] > 338 and mouse[1] < 428:
                    Credits()
                # If the user presses the Options button
                elif mouse[0] > 221 and mouse[0] < 451 and mouse[1] > 468 and mouse[1] < 561:
                    print("Options")
                # If the user presses the Exit Button
                elif mouse[0] > 832 and mouse[0] < 1067 and mouse[1] > 468 and mouse[1] < 561:
                    Running = False
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Running = False

def Credits():
    black = [0, 0, 0]
    screen.fill(black)
    CreditFile = open("Credits.txt", "r")
    CreditFileText = CreditFile.read()
    print(CreditFileText)
    CreditText = Menufont.render(CreditFileText, True, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(CreditText, (30, 30))
    pygame.display.update
    # This makes it so the cross in the corner is able to work
    Running = True
    while Running == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Running = False


MainMenu()
```

The menu buttons can be seen with the image and the exit button does work as well as the other ones, however when I use the credits button, it gives the 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable' error and I have no idea why.

Comment: You have a variable named "Credits" in "MainMenu" that is some rendered text and this overrides the function with the same name. Name one of them something else

Comment: Safe fam. I am a very new programmer so these errors are difficult to see

Comment: No worries, experienced programmers still get these issues, sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes

Comment: you have not provided credits.txt yet . code is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are two problems, they are following

1. Same name of Credits menu text & Credits function
2. Typo error in Credits function to update screen `pygame.display.update`

The fixed code is following

```
#Importing all necessary scripts
import pygame
import time
import sys


#Initiating pygame
pygame.init()

#Creating the fonts for the game
Menufont = pygame.font.SysFont('Bahnschrift SemiBold', 70)

#Creating the window for where the game is able to be played
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

#Getting the height and the width of the screen into a variable
width = screen.get_width()
height = screen.get_height()

#Creating a Procedure for the Main Menu
def MainMenu():
    # Creating the main menu with a background image which has been modified to provide
    background = pygame.image.load('Main Menu Background.png')
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    # Creating text for the buttons for the main menu of the game
    PlaySolo = Menufont.render("Play Solo", True, (3, 3, 116))
    PlayMulti = Menufont.render("Play Multi", True, (3, 3, 116))
    Leaders = Menufont.render("Leaders", True, (3, 3, 116))
    Credits = Menufont.render("Credits", True, (3, 3, 116))
    Options = Menufont.render("Options", True, (3, 3, 116))
    Exit = Menufont.render("Exit", True, (3, 3, 116))

    # Placing the text for the buttons onto the main menu for the game
    screen.blit(PlaySolo, (229, 221))
    screen.blit(PlayMulti, (833, 221))
    screen.blit(Leaders, (243, 359))
    screen.blit(Credits, (863, 359))
    screen.blit(Options, (241, 492))
    screen.blit(Exit, (906, 492))

    # updating the menu for the game
    pygame.display.update()

    # This makes it so the cross in the corner is able to work
    Running = True
    while Running == True:
        # Provides information whilst the programme is running
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                # This gets the x and y co-ordinates for where the mouse is
                mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(mouse)
                # If the user presses the Play Solo Button
                if mouse[0] > 221 and mouse[0] < 454 and mouse[1] > 199 and mouse[1] < 289:
                    print("Play Solo")
                # If the user presses the Play Multi Button
                elif mouse[0] > 832 and mouse[0] < 1067 and mouse[1] > 199 and mouse[1] < 289:
                    print("Play Multi")
                # If the user presses the Leaders Button
                elif mouse[0] > 221 and mouse[0] < 454 and mouse[1] > 338 and mouse[1] < 428:
                    print("Leaders")
                # If the user presses the Credits Button
                elif mouse[0] > 832 and mouse[0] < 1067 and mouse[1] > 338 and mouse[1] < 428:
                    print("Credits")
                    RenderCredits()
                # If the user presses the Options button
                elif mouse[0] > 221 and mouse[0] < 451 and mouse[1] > 468 and mouse[1] < 561:
                    print("Options")
                # If the user presses the Exit Button
                elif mouse[0] > 832 and mouse[0] < 1067 and mouse[1] > 468 and mouse[1] < 561:
                    Running = False
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Running = False

def RenderCredits():
    black = [0, 0, 0]
    screen.fill(black)
    CreditFile = open("Credits.txt", "r")
    CreditFileText = CreditFile.read()
    print(CreditFileText)
    CreditText = Menufont.render(CreditFileText, True, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(CreditText, (30, 30))
    pygame.display.update()
    # This makes it so the cross in the corner is able to work
    Running = True
    while Running == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Running = False


MainMenu()
```

[image]

and the demo credits rendering

[image]